# Integration of Squid Proxy to Anonymous Open Proxies to cache html response from Anonymous proxies

Tags: proxy, squid, http-caching

I need to Cache html response from anonymous proxies using squid caching server. However my requirement is something as given:

From client machine  I need to connect to anonymous proxy with credentials IP and port. All my request  are routed through local squid proxy server.

I tried with the given configurations on squid but not able to cache the response when I connect to the origin as following:

```
squidclinet -h <IP-Anonymous_Proxy> -p <Port> -u <username> -w <Password> <https://www.example.com>
```

However I am able to cache using following method:

```
squidclient -h  <IP-squid_proxy> -p  <Port>  -u <username> -w <Password>
```

My squid.conf file

```
# General

http_port 3128
visible_hostname Proxy
forwarded_for delete
via off

# Log

logformat squid %tg.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %[un %Sh/%<a %mt
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid

# Cache

cache_dir aufs /var/cache/squid 1024 16 256
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
cache deny QUERY

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0


# Network ACL

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 possible internal network

# Port ACL

acl SSL_ports port 443          # https
acl SSL_ports port 563          # snews
acl SSL_ports port 873          # rync
acl Safe_ports port 80 8080     # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 563     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
###Cache Peer
cache_peer <Anonymous-Proxy> parent <Port> 0 no-query default login=username:password
never_direct allow all

http_access allow all
icp_access allow all
#always_direct allow all

# Request Headers Forcing

request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all

# Response Headers Spoofing

reply_header_access Via deny all
reply_header_access X-Cache deny all
reply_header_access X-Cache-Lookup deny all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cache HTTPS as it is encrypted.
Squid is a HTTP cache only.
HTTPS queries of clients like browsers, `wget` or `curl` can only be routed through Squid with the `CONNECT` method but not be cached there.

While the `ssl bump` method supports caching, it involves generating fake SSL certificates and installing a fake CA certificate on the clients. This constitutes a man-in-the-middle attack.
While this is possible, it is not recommended except in special cases justifying such an approach.
The objective of caching alone does not justify using the `ssl bump` method.

Comment: Squid is a caching proxy for the Web supporting HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and more. It reduces bandwidth and improves response times by caching and reusing frequently-requested web pages. Squid has extensive access controls and makes a great server accelerator. It runs on most available operating systems, including Windows and is licensed under the GNU GPL.

Comment: Also I read about ssl bump being used for caching https. Also my question was I was I was not able cache while using following command as client with squid being my transparent proxy
squidclient -h <IP-Anonymous_Proxy> -p <Port> -u <username> -w <Password> <https://www.example.com> with

Comment: Your question was about `https://www.example.com`. While squid does support HTTPS, it supports it by routing through using the CONNECT method and not caching. I'm extending my answer to cover the `ssl bump` method.

Comment: Also would like to know when using squid as a transparent proxy, does it cache the information when client connects to origin server through anonymous proxy server. In this case squid is used only as a gateway between client and anonymous proxy.

Comment: Yes ist does, but still not HTTPS but only HTTP.

Comment: Do you mean to say using cache_peer in the configuration? With cache_peer configuration, using anonymous proxy it does but how about without using cache peer. I tried to connect to the origin using anonymous  proxy using squidclient <anonymous proxy> <port> <login>. In this case the packet was routed through squid but was not able to store any headers.

Comment: Squid's ability to cache something is independent of whether you use it as a transparent proxy or anonymous or with a login: It caches HTTP traffic and cannot cache HTTPS traffic except if you use the `ssl bump` method what you should do only in special cases, but not to achieve caching.